# Can doPost() run itself?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
function doPost(e) {  
  var msg= JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var shitText = msg.messaging[0].message.text;
  var senderId = msg.messaging[0].sender_id;

  Logger.log(e)
  .
  .
  .
  (do something)
}
```

I use `doPost()` smoothly.

But when I create the (e) objects to pass to it and try to run itself,

the syntax errors tells that

"It cannot load the contents properties of undefined".

Like picture show below.

[image]

Can't the `doPost()` run itself?

Or just to need post the data to it to do functions?

Thank you.

Comment: it's your function, so you should call it with an argument that satisfies the code you wrote

Comment: Yes.I create to e objects to be arguments,and assure that the arguments's structure correctly. But when use doPost() run itself,it runs error like picture.

Comment: if you call doPost like doPost() then you're not calling it with any argument at all - perhaps you should elaborate your code to show where and how doPost is "running itself"

Comment: Like the HTML click event. When you click the button and alert text.
And you can use click() without human click.

Comment: Is it possible to run doPost() without the human post?

Comment: I don't know how to elaborate and simplify my example dircetly.Can you teach me about that?

Comment: Where is the created `e` object and how are you calling `doPost()` with the created `e` object? How is it passed to doPost()? `perhaps you should elaborate your code to show where and how doPost is "running itself"` [Edit] to show that code.

Answer (score 0):

`doPost()` can run by itself without initializing the `e` variable in the parameter. I think the problem comes from the contents property in the JSON string, so you should look at it. It has a 's'. 
Also you need to post the e variable here (which should be a nested JSON string), or we don't know what is wrong with the codes.

You can try and run this code, this will work. The example below showcases that you can initialize `e` variable inside a parameter to ensure that the function still work even when you call `doPost()` without any parameter.

```
function abc(e = '{\"sample\": {\"someitem\": {\"thesearecool\": [{\"neat\": \"wow\"},{\"neat\": \"tubular\"}]}}}'){
var msg= JSON.parse(e);
console.log(msg.sample.someitem.thesearecool[0].neat)
}

abc();
```

Edit: if you are using JS, don't use `e` as varriable, you will mistake it sometimes with `(e)` as event.

Answer (score 0):

`e` in the Apps Script function `doPost(e)` stands for an **event object** which will only be initialized when the event takes place.

`e.postData.contents` are the contents of data obtained from a post request.

if you run the function manually, without a trigger event taking place - there are no post data contents linked to an event and this gives you the error.

If you just want to test your function manually, you need to use `doPost()` without the `e` and assign a value to your post data contents manually.